# Function which increments a value by 125 from based on an array Index - javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to generate a number in increments of 125 from index 1 based on the index while looping over an array. If the index is 0, it should print 100. If the index is 1, 100 + 125 = 225, index is 2, 225 + 125 = 350 and so on. How do I do this? This is what I have.

```js
const rows = 5;

const rowArray = new Array(rows).fill(' ');

const result = rowArray.map((i, index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    return 100
  }
  if (index === 1) {
    return 225
  }
  return index * 100 + 125

})

console.log(result)
```

Expected output:

```
[100, 225, 350, 475, 600, 725]
```

Can someone help me out with this math? Thanks.

Comment: It should be `index * 125 + 100`. You got the multiplication and addition backwards.

Comment: Note that the exceptions for index 0 and 1 are not necessary. `0 * 125 + 100` produces `100` and `1 * 125 + 100` produces `225`. The whole thing could be shortened to a one-liner. `const result = Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, index) => index * 125 + 100)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` function can be rewritten as this:

```js
const result = rowArray.map((i, index) => index * 125 + 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const rows = 5;

const rowArray = new Array(rows).fill(' ');

const result = rowArray.map((i, index) => {
  return 100 + 125*index

})

console.log(result)
```

This should be better: you were multiplying 100, and not 125. Note that `index===1` and `index===0` are still included in `100 + 125*index`

Answer (score 0):

By the way, `Array#reduce` is perfect for this:

```
const rows = 5;
const rowArray = new Array(rows).fill(' ');
const result = [100];

rowArray.reduce((a, b) => (b = a + 125, result.push(b), b), 100);

console.log(result);
```